# Can't figure out how to reduce the amount of lines in my function to 25

Tags: c, function

I'm making my own version of the split function in C but I'm limited to have only 25 lines of code per function. I've been stuck and I don't know how to solve the issue.

I have tried solving the issue by creating separate functions, but those have 5 parameters and the limit is 4. Just like declaring variables on separate lines and having a newline after the variables.

Does anyone know how I can change my split function to have 25 lines or less?

```
char    **ft_split(char const *s, char c)
{
        int             index;
        char    **strings;
        size_t  i;
        size_t  j;

        index = -1;
        i = 0;
        j = 0;
        strings = malloc((number_of_substrings(s, c) + 1) * sizeof(char *));
        if (!s || !strings)
                return (0);
        while (i <= ft_strlen(s))
        {
                if (s[i] != c && index < 0)
                        index = i;
                else if ((s[i] == c || i == ft_strlen(s)) && index >= 0)
                {
                        if ((strings[j] = copy_word(s, index, i)) == 0)
                        {
                                cleanup_strings(strings, j);
                                return (NULL);
                        }
                        j++;
                        index = -1;
                }
                i++;
        }
        strings[j] = 0;
        return (strings);
}
```

These are are the other functions I use in my function:

```
static int      number_of_substrings(char const *s, char c)
{
        int     index;
        int     count;

        index = 0;
        count = 0;
        while (*s)
        {
                if (*s != c && count == 0)
                {
                        count = 1;
                        index++;
                }
                else if (*s == c)
                        count = 0;
                s++;
        }
        return (index);
}

static char     *copy_word(const char *s, int start, int finish)
{
        int             index;
        char    *substring;

        index = 0;
        substring = malloc((finish - start + 1) * sizeof(char));
        if (!substring)
                return (NULL);
        while (start < finish)
                substring[index++] = s[start++];
        substring[index] = '\0';
        return (substring);
}

void    cleanup_strings(char **strings, size_t j)
{
    while (j > 0)
    {
        j--;
        free(strings[j]);
    }
    free(strings);
}
```

Comment: `int index = -1; size_t i = 0, j = 0;` on two lines will shorten by several lines.

Comment: From the edit: is there a peculiar demand telling you to use lines and then tell you not to use too many? It's archaic demanding that all variables be declared at the start of a function.

Comment: Yeah, there is a 'norm' I need to follow. Some of the rules are that a function can't be more than 25 lines and each variable needs to be declared on a new line. Split is a function that takes a string and splits into an array of the individual words in that string.

Comment: Functions should be short enough to be fairly easy to follow and understand, but an arbitrary limit on the number of lines seems particularly silly.

Comment: (switching your code formatting style to One True Brace will shave off some lines)

Comment: Your `while (i <= ft_strlen(s))` loop could be a `for` loop over `i`. That would save 2-3 lines.